Are fixed effects not being evaluated by the model?
I have a mixed effect model that includes some variables as fixed effects and some as random effects.
All of them are defined as factors, and I set appropriate reference levels. var_one includes two levels, var_two includes four levels, var_three includes three levels.
# define formula
formula_rda <- "var_one+var_two+var_three+Condition(rand_one+rand_two)"

this model is being used to run a partial RDA ordination and then an anova.cca to test the constraints. Something like this:
# run partial RDA
partial_rda <- ordinate(data, "RDA", formula=as.formula(formula_rda))
# perform the test
signif_test <- anova.cca(partial_rda, step=1000, by="terms")

However, what I get as an output does include only one variable:
Permutation test for rda under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999
        
Model: rda(formula = OTU ~ var_one + var_two + var_three + 
   Condition(rand_one + rand_two), data = data)
            Df  Variance      F Pr(>F)
Var_one      1    347279 0.2253  0.867
Residual    82 126409291  

Question is: why are var_two and var_three not included in the results from the anova.cca test?
EDIT:
If I remove the random factors from the model:
# define formula
    formula_rda <- "var_one+var_two+var_three"

then, all the variables are evaluated and the anova.cca returns some meaningful results:
Permutation test for rda under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: rda(formula = OTU ~ var_one + var_two+var_three, data = data)
                  Df Variance       F Pr(>F)    
var_one            1    10503  2.3576  0.061 .  
var_two            3   145362 10.8762  0.001 ***
var_three          2     8459  0.9486  0.423    
Residual         114   508328 


Probably rand_one and rand_two explained everything that var_two and var_three could explain. Nothing was left for them to explain and they are not shown.

what if the variance was hidden by the random factors? if i remove them then var_two and var_three are able to explain some variance...and one is even "significant".

Your comment was just the same that I wrote, but in your own words.
